# rotating mod_security logs with rotatelog

Tags: logging, httpd, mod-security

I would like to rotate `mod_security` logs with `rotatelogs`, as this does not need a restart of the `httpd`, like `logrotate` does. However, it seems like `mod_security` does not want to work together with `rotatelogs`. In my mod security config I have

```
SecDebugLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.%Y.%m.%d 86400"
```

This gives me at startup of my httpd:

```
Syntax error on line 45 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
ModSecurity: Failed to open debug log file: /etc/httpd/|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.%Y.%m.%d 86400
```

So I assume the mod security log directives do not play together with rotatelogs. Has anyone found a way around this?

**EDIT** I found [logging through a fifo](https://serverfault.com/questions/360530/log-through-a-fifo-then-redirect-to-a-file), but as the answers explain this seems not to be such a great idea.

**EDIT 2** It works for the Audit log, but not for the debug log.

Comment: Does the debug log file exists?

Comment: No, it should get created with the defined name (which changes over time). Also, I found that its not such a big problem, as the debug log - up untill a certain debug log level - contains the same information as the httpd error log. So under usual operations one can just scip the debug log